# How to read output of running QProcess and save specific data to variable?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm going to get status from command line video player. When it's running, it outputs following line among many others.

> [update_state]pid:0 status=PLAYING(last:PLAYING) err=0x0 curtime=4 (ms:4983) fulltime=-1 lsttime=4

So I'd like to read that output and save it to variable in real-time.

```
#include "system.h"

QProcess * player = new QProcess();

QString current_status;
QString last_status;
int current_time;
int full_time;
int lsttime;

system::system(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void system::start(QString url)
{
    player->start("player", QStringList(url));
}
```

UPDATE below

```
#include "system.h"


QProcess *player = new QProcess();
system::system(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}
void system::start(QString url)
{
    stop();
    player->start("player", QStringList(url));
    connect(player,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this,SLOT(readyReadStandardOutput()));
    connect(player,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT(readyReadStandardError()));
}

void system::readyReadStandardOutput(){
    qDebug() << player->readAllStandardOutput();
}

void system::readyReadStandardError(){
    //player->readAllStandardError();
}
```

Comment: No idea how this is done in QT but the concept you are looking for is called a *pipe*. You need to open a pipe to the child process and you can read it's output from that.

Comment: Just connect to the [`QProcess::readyReadStandardOutput`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput) signal and process the output from the child as/when it arrives.

Comment: @G.M. I have updated with code with as you suggested. However qDebug() is printing about once in every 15 seconds. I need less than 1 second accuracy. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: It's 15 sec, probably because your process outputs after 15 seconds.

Comment: What happens if you run the player at the command line?  Do you only get output every 15s in that case?  It's possible that the player changes its behaviour depending on whether or not its output is a tty device.

Comment: @G.M. That's exactly the case. I tested by "player <url> >> output.txt" then checked with "tail -f ". It looks like buffering issue, not QT issue.